# How to get a particular key of a nested json with of a known structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json data of a known structure. But the key names will vary. I need to know the key names.

for example I have json named data

```
{
  "class": {
    "I": {
      "students": {
        "112": [
          "kabilan",
          "1001"
        ]
      }
    },
    "II": {
      "students": {
        "113": [
          "Ashok",
          "1002"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the first key 'class' from using `Object.keys(data)[0]`,
Now how can i get the key name where it says 'students'?

Comment: This is not a duplicate that question does not have nested properties

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Comment: That makes the different in how to get the inner key name. if you dont understand the question kindly state your doubt.

Comment: If you already know how to get the key name of the first level, you just have to do the exact same thing to get the next level. If you have `var first = Object.keys(data)[0]` then the second level is`var second = Object.keys(data[first])[0]` and so on.

Comment: `I have json data of a known structure. But the key names will vary.`?

Comment: I wanted the third level. It return errors. `can't convert undefined to object`

Comment: @Xotic750.  on different occasion the keys will vary and i need to get those keys.

Comment: So what you actually want are the keys of the third level (depth) of an unknown structure? And all the keys leading to them?

Comment: Probably that is what i want i think @Xotic750.

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify your question. Is `students` always present and at a depth of 3 in your structure of objects with unknown keys?

Comment: yes. But need not be 'students'. I needed the key name at level 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all properties and their values.

```js
var data = { "class": { "I": { "students": { "112": ["kabilan", "1001"] } }, "II": { "students": { "113": ["Ashok", "1002"] } } } };

function getProperties(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        document.write(k + '<br>');
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            getProperties(o[k]);
        }
    });
}
getProperties(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var f_loop in data){
     for(var s_loop in data[f_loop]){
       console.log(Object.keys(data[f_loop][s_loop]))
     }
}
```

Maybe it can help U? But I do not know what U actually want to do?

If U want to get those keys ,why not choose `JSON.parse()` to decode this json?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but here is some code that may help you, if I am understanding your requirement from the comments.

This will get you the path of keys at a particular depth, as shown in green.

If `students` is the key that you are looking for then the other parts of the code show you how you can deal with filtering for that key and how to join the path keys to access the object.

```js
// This will get the path (keys) to a particular depth
var getPaths = (function() {
  function getPathInternal(object, depth, acc, current) {
    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
      return false;
    }
    if (!Number.isFinite(depth) || depth < 1) {
      return true;
    }
    depth -= 1;
    var snapshot = current.slice();
    Object.keys(object).some(function(key) {
      current.push(key);
      if (getPathInternal(object[key], depth, acc, current) === true) {
        return true;
      }
      if (depth === 1) {
        acc.push(current);
      }
      current = snapshot;
    });
    return acc;
  }
  return function getPath(object, depth) {
    var array = getPathInternal(object, depth, [], []);
    return Array.isArray(array) ? array : [];
  };
}());

// Your JSON
var json = '{"class":{"I":{"students":{"112":["kabilan","1001"]}},"II":{"students":{"113":["Ashok","1002"]}}}}';
// Your object
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// Path to what depth?
var depth = 3;
// Array of path keys to depth
var pathsDepth3 = getPaths(obj, depth);
document.getElementById('paths').textContent = JSON.stringify(pathsDepth3, null, 2);
console.log(pathsDepth3);

// I have decided this is the path key that I want
var iWant = 'students';
// Filter out any paths that don't end in the key I want
var pathsStudents = pathsDepth3.filter(function(path) {
  return path.slice().pop() === iWant;
});
// Access the objects that I want
pathsStudents.forEach(function(path) {
  var students = obj;
  path.forEach(function(part) {
    students = students[part];
  });
  document.getElementById('students').textContent += JSON.stringify(students, null, 2) + '\n';
  console.log(students);
});
```

```css
#paths {
  background-color: green;
}
#students {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<pre id="paths"></pre>
<pre id="students"></pre>
```